# How can I check if a iframe will work

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

How can I see if a iframe will work.  For example I know google will not work in a iframe.  Is their a way to test the iframe to see if the src works and if not replace it with some default src?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```
var testFrame = false;
var newUrl = "http://newUrl.com";

$('#iFrame').load(function(){
   testFrame = true;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function() {
      if(testFrame == true){
         $iframe.attr('src',newUrl);
      }
   }, 5000);
});
```

This waits 5 seconds, you can change 5000 to a different millisecond amount